# How to create pipeline compatible Jenkins job which only looks at pull requests to master

Tags: git, github, jenkins, groovy

I am creating a Jenkins job that must be compatible with the Pipeline-as-code feature (Pipeline job, Github Organization Job, or Multibranch Pipeline job).

None of the actual branches themselves need be built. The job should only trigger when a pull request is initiated to protected branches matching a specific naming pattern (these would be the master branches and branches for different upcoming releases). The job would then checkout that pull request, build it, run tests, etc. It would then send a status to that pull request stating whether the tests passed or failed.

The protected branch would require that status to be passed, and on success the pull request would automatically be accepted into master/release branch.

As much of this process as possible should be in the groovy script to take advantage of having the process version-controlled. A lot of the available plugins seem to be missing/incompatible with at least one part of the overall process.

The repo is hosted on a Github Enterprise server.